# Why is this showing "SP2-0552: Bind variable "SEL" not declared." in sql plus?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2      SEL NUMBER(3);
  3      ans VARCHAR(20);
  4  BEGIN:
  5      SEL := &SEL ;
  6      CASE SEL
  7  WHEN 1 THEN ans := 'SUNDAY';
  8  WHEN 2 THEN ans := 'MONDAY';
  9  WHEN 3 THEN ans := 'TUESDAY';
 10  WHEN 4 THEN ans := 'WEDNESDAY';
 11  WHEN 5 THEN ans := 'THURSDAY';
 12  WHEN 6 THEN ans := 'FRIDAY';
 13  WHEN 7 THEN ans := 'SATURDAY';
 14
 15      END CASE;
 16      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' CORRESPONDING DAY FOR THE NUMBER '||SEL||' IS '||DAY);
 17  END;
 18  /


Enter value for sel: 3
old   5:     SEL := &SEL ;
new   5:     SEL := 3 ;
SP2-0552: Bind variable "SEL" not declared.
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems in your block:

1. There is a colon after `BEGIN`, it's not supposed to be there
2. In your output there is a the `DAY` variable that is not declared, it should be the variable `ans`.

Below is the working version:

```
DECLARE
    SEL NUMBER(3);
    ans VARCHAR(20);
BEGIN
    SEL := &SEL ;
    CASE SEL
    WHEN 1 THEN ans := 'SUNDAY';
    WHEN 2 THEN ans := 'MONDAY';
    WHEN 3 THEN ans := 'TUESDAY';
    WHEN 4 THEN ans := 'WEDNESDAY';
    WHEN 5 THEN ans := 'THURSDAY';
    WHEN 6 THEN ans := 'FRIDAY';
    WHEN 7 THEN ans := 'SATURDAY';

   END CASE;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' CORRESPONDING DAY FOR THE NUMBER '||SEL||' IS '||ans);
END;
/
```